# R sf: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to calculate the centroids of a set of polygons.

My dataset, `geodata`, contains five columns including one `geometry` column of class `sfc_GEOMETRY`, with 45759 rows.

When I run `sf::st_centroid(geodata)`, I get the following message

> Error in CPL_geos_op("centroid", x, numeric(0), integer(0), numeric(0),  : Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring.
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In st_centroid.sf(geodata) :
>     st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries of x
>
> 2: In st_centroid.sfc(st_geometry(x), of_largest_polygon = of_largest_polygon) :
>     st_centroid does not give correct centroids for longitude/latitude data

- Should I run a loop to detect which geometry is not closed?
- Is this a problem with the class of my geometry? Should it be `sfc_MULTIPOLYGON`?

### Possible solution:

I was encountering this problem when reading in a list of files through a loop. The loop would read in the files and then `rbind` them together into `geodata`, and *then* calculate the centroid:

```
for(i in 1:length(list)){
  file <- st_read(list[i])
  geodata <- rbind(geodata, file) #geodata is here a void sf object
}
geocent <- st_centroid(geodata)
```

When I calculated the centroids *within* the loop (for each file in the list), the error disappeared.

```
for(i in 1:length(list)){
  file <- st_read(list[i])
  file <- st_centroid(file)
  geocent <- rbind(geodata, file) #geodata is here a void sf object
}
```

Hence, I think the problem lay in the binding operation.

- Perhaps I had not defined my void `sf` object in the right manner.
- Perhaps `rbind` was not the appropriate function, or I should have specified its parameters.

Comment: Does it fail like that on subsets of your data? On every row? On one, or a few rows? What's different about those rows? Hard to tell without your data, so you should investigate this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to run a loop to find which geometry is bad.  The `st_is_valid()` function should tell you which row(s) have the problem.

It looks like one of your geometries might be made up of an incorrect number of points.

More info about finding and fixing the problem at r-spatial: https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2017/03/19/invalid.html

Comment: When I run `any(is.na(st_is_valid(geodata)))`, I get `FALSE`. Is this an error from `st_is_valid` because `lwgeom` isn't installed (`sf_extSoftVersion()['lwgeom']` yields `NA`)?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your specific problem without a reproducible error.