# st_within and st_valid help - Illegal Geometries in Big Files

Tags: r, bigdata, spatial

I have a 'big data' file that I am geocoding. I am trying to match a file with 30 million points, through within matching to a file with 5million polygons. I have the following code and error:

```
df_spatialjoin<- st_join(df_points, df_polygons, join=st_within)
```

> Error in CPL_geos_binop(st_geometry(x), st_geometry(y), op, par,
> pattern,  :    Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: Points of
> LinearRing do not form a closed linestring.

I believe, from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749442/r-sf-points-of-linearring-do-not-form-a-closed-linestring), that this means that some of the polygons aren't closed, so I tried to find out which with :

st_is_valid(df_polygons)

but it's been running all night. I've already set my memory limit high and stripped out all the variables I don't need. Any advice on other ways to do it that may speed up the process? Like, can I just drop the ones that don't work rather than interrogating them through st_is_valid?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps assume the polygons are `all` just line strings that need closing so you drop testing and get polygons in one pass [concaveman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290170/convert-a-linestring-into-a-closed-polygon-when-the-points-are-not-in-order). The previously closed ones won't be offended and you can move on to your point in polygon problem.